# Where/when should I remove the relationship type to avoid an unknown keys warning?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data with a server application that follows the json:api standard. When I normalize the response from the server, I'm adding a `relationshipType` attribute from the `links` so that Ember Data knows what type of model to build when the relationship is polymorphic.

For example, here's the response from the server:

```
{
  "members": {
    "id": "1",
    "created_at": "2014-10-15T18:35:00.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-15T18:35:00.000Z",
    "links": {
      "user": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "users",
        "href": "http://test.host/api/v1/users/1"
      },
      "organization": {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "customers",
        "href": "http://test.host/api/v1/customers/2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `organization` relationship is polymorphic, and the `type` in this instance is `customers`.

In the Ember application, I'm normalizing the response into following (which follows the `RESTSerializer` convention):

```
{
  "members": {
    "id": "1",
    "created_at": "2014-10-15T18:35:00.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-15T18:35:00.000Z",
    "user": "1",
    "userType": "users",
    "organization": "2",
    "organizationType": "customers"
  }
}
```

This works, and Ember Data builds the correct user relationship and organization relationship (using the `Customer` model).

But, I'm receiving the following warning:

```
WARNING: The payload for '(subclass of DS.Model)' contains these unknown keys:
[userType,organizationType]. Make sure they've been defined in your model.
```

I'd like to remove these `relationshipType` keys and their values after they've been used.

Where should I do this?

Comment: As of now, it doesn't look possible to suppress this without changing the implementation of the [#push method in the Store](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/163f491b2aa7ae2489d30e92da056ff95315210b/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1352). See [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2599) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api? I may have some other overrides in my app to handle polymorphism but hopefully the package will get you closer.

Also see my pending [PR](https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api/pull/57).

Comment: I did, but it didn't handle all aspects of the JSON:API variant that I had chosen, so I wrote an adapter and serializer heavily inspired by it. But thanks for the recommendation.